# IIS large amount of time before loading

Tags: iis, asp.net

I am running an ASP.NET 3.5 website on IIS 6 with Server 2003. Whenever I modify any of the ASPX files, any page on the site then takes about 2-3 minutes before it starts to load. Even the smallest modification causes this to happen.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because IIS is recompiling your application's modules. You could try [pre-compiling](http://odetocode.com/Articles/417.aspx) your application outside of IIS, which would prevent customer impact.

Comment: I am in the process of developing the site at the moment, and is not in production yet, so frequent changes are necessary. Is there any way to stop if recompiling?

Comment: If you stop it from recompiling, how will your changes have taken effect?

Comment: hmm OK, so how do I find out whats taking so long to load? It's only a very basic website.

Comment: Do you have console access to the server?  you might wanna try ProcMon or FileMon to see what files and processes are being activated. 2-3 minutes sounds tooo long for a compile of a simple site.  I'd look for a network timeout, somewhere. DNS lookup, something like that.  Sorry can't be more specific, it's  just that 2-3 minutes doesn't smell like compilation latency, to me.

Comment: Yes, I have full RDP access. I've checked process explorer, and the CPU usage is usually around 5-10%, although task manager is reporting 70% or higher all the time, even though there are no processes or services which are using the processing power. Bear in mind it is a vps.

I may end up just re-imaging the server.

Comment: Do you have "Show processes for all users" in Task Manager checked? If not, the graph will show 70%, but you would only see the CPU being used under your user id.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen in environments that have the following conditions:

- the application uses DLLs that are digitally signed (especially third party)
- the server is behind a firewall, or is unable to resolve external DNS entries (such as the CRL)

Solution:

1. Open C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet.config
2. Add the following entry:  in the  section.
3. Save it, recycle your worker process.

(if 64-bit, make sure you make the corresponding change under Framework64)

More documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629393.aspx)